# Passing value from struct array with segue : index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, struct, xcode7, segue

Hopefully this will be the last question i need to ask!
I have been looking into this for 48 hours now and i still cannot find answers.

Here is the code i am using:

DataSource.swift:

```
struct Game {
    var name : String
    var cheats : [Cheat]
}
struct Cheat {
    var name : String
    var code : String
    var desc : String
}
```

GameListViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GameListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var gamesArray = [Game]()
    var cheatsArray = [Cheat]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        gamesArray = [Game(name: "Game1", cheats: [Cheat(name: "cheat1", code: "code1", desc: "desc1")])]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gamesArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
        cell.textLabel?.text = gamesArray[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CheatListViewController

        var DataPass : Cheat
        DataPass = cheatsArray[indexPath.row]
        DestViewController.cheatnameArray = DataPass.name

        var DataPass2 : Cheat
        DataPass2 = cheatsArray[indexPath.row]
        DestViewController.cheatcodeArray = DataPass2.code

        var DataPass3 : Cheat
        DataPass3 = cheatsArray[indexPath.row]
        DestViewController.cheatdescArray = DataPass3.desc
    }

}
```

CheatListViewController.swift

```
class CheatListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cheatcodeArray = String()
    var cheatnameArray = String()
    var cheatdescArray = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

When i select "Game 1" from gamesArray i instantly receive an index out of range error from the first instance of "DataPass".
I have structured my datasource in this way so that i do not have to edit arrays separately and keep my objects neat and tidy.

If someone could point me in the right direction i would be forever grateful !

Kind regards
Rory

Comment: What is the value of indexPath.row ?
What is the value of cheatsArray.count ?

Comment: If i understand correctly, cheatsArray.count should be 1 as their is an instance of [Cheat] in my gamesArray..
Or am i totally misunderstanding the way in which struct - arrays work?

Comment: I can't find any place in your code where you add a cheat to your cheatsArray, this has to be done manually.. like you do with gamesArray..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like you haven't populated your `cheatsArray` variable with any cheats. That's why you receive an index out of range exception.

From your code it is a bit hard to understand what you're looking to achieve, but I think I have it..

Notice I use an optional binding to unwrap the `destinationViewController`, this is safe because any other segue performed will also trigger the same `prepareForSegue`.

```
if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? CheatListViewController {

    let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    var game = gamesArray[indexPath.row]

    destViewController.cheatnameArray = game.cheats.map({ $0.name })
    destViewController.cheatcodeArray = game.cheats.map({ $0.code })
    destViewController.cheatdescArray = game.cheats.map({ $0.desc })
}
```

Change your arrays to actual string arrays and not strings..

```
var cheatcodeArray = [String]()
var cheatnameArray = [String]()
var cheatdescArray = [String]()
```

[The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: " Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to closure result type 'String' "

Comment: Sorry Laffen, it did work, i just forgot to reverse the changes i made before your answer!!
Awesome stuff thank you so much :)

Comment: NP, glad it helped =)